# Git insufficient permission error on commit

Tags: git, ubuntu

I just gt a new Linux machine (Ubuntu) and I'm trying to set up Git on a repository I've been working on for the last year. Before I switched machines, I started getting

```
insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
```

I was unable to solve the problem there and thought it might have been because I was using WSL and I couldn't change the permissions for the Windows files. Interestingly, I did not get the error when I ran Git Bash, so that was my workaround.

Now that I've switched to a Linux machine, I tried again and I'm getting the same error. I've tried various chmod and chown commands. I've set the sharedRepository to group. When I list the contents of .git/objects, there are no dirs owned by root; they're all myuser:myuser (I'm the only one using the repository). I can run the commits using sudo, but then I have to run every git command with sudo because some dirs and files do change to root.

Anyone?

Comment: Does it work after `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser .git`?

Comment: Nope. That's what I ran.

Comment: Does it happen for every commit, or just some? What’s the output if you add `strace -Z` before `git commit`?

Comment: Every commit that I've tried. Z doesn't seem to be a valid option. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Find failing syscalls. You might need a newer version of `strace` for that. Maybe just the full output of `strace git commit …`, then?

Comment: It's quite long and I have no idea what I'm looking for....

Comment: Just the few lines leading up to “insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects” should be enough.

Comment: `access(".git/objects/25/1544a1d7184a75495392cef0017c4e6e1b8d8b", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getpid()                                = 5054
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/objects/25/tmp_obj_3Wuu8j", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0444) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "error: insufficient permission f"..., 88error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
) = 88
close(4)  `

Comment: `ls -ld .git/objects/25`?

Comment: `drwxrwsrwx+ 2 nomi nomi 4096 Feb 20 15:30 .git/objects/25`

Comment: `s` is a bit odd… if you `ls -l .git/objects`, do most of the directories also have that `+` at the end of the first column? What does `getfacl .git/objects/25` show?

Comment: All have both the s and the +. `getfacl` has about 25 lines of output. The `#flags` line has `-s-`.

Comment: Those 25 lines would be helpful. Also, it’s probably worth trying cloning this freshly into a separate directory just to avoid interference from any previous fix attempts.

Comment: The comments section is longer than the original post....         `# file: .git/objects/25/
# owner: nomi
# group: nomi
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
user:500:rwx
user:503:rwx
user:nobody:---
user:3000007:rwx
user:3000021:rwx
group::---
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:user:500:rwx
default:user:503:rwx
default:user:nobody:---
default:user:3000007:rwx
default:user:3000021:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
`

Comment: The `s` (setuid) in the group permissions is Linux (and FreeBSD) specific and controls how the group-ownership propagates during new file creation, so that's just a red herring. It's more likely you're being caught by the high-security modes of something like [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux).

Comment: SELinux doesn't look like it's installed/enabled.